# Java completableFuture - multithreading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I am new to multithreading and feel confused about it.

I am trying to create two parallel threads, in each thread, it first calls an api-1 and get the response, then use that response to call the second api-2 and get the final result.

The first version code is like:

```java
CompletableFuture<List<String>> listFuture1 = CompletableFuture
   .supplyAsync(() -> {
      List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
      try {
         res = callAPI1(id);
         return res;
      } catch(Exception e) {
        //...
      }
      return res; 
});

CompletableFuture<List<String>> listFuture2 = CompletableFuture
   .supplyAsync(() -> {
      List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
      try {
         res = callFirstAPI2(id);
         return res;
      } catch(Exception e) {
        //...
      }
      return res; 
});

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(listFuture1.join());
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(listFuture2.join());


List<String> res1 = callAPI2(list1);
List<String> res2 = callAPI2(list2);
```

The above code works correctly but it is very slow to get the final result, and looks like the callFirstAPI1() and callFirstAPI2() are not happening in the same thread.

Then I tried this way:

```java
public List<String> getList(int id) {

  CompletableFuture<List<String>> res = CompletableFuture
   .supplyAsync(() -> {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      try {
         list= callAPI1(id);
         return list;
      } catch(Exception e) {
      }
      return list; 
  }).thenApply(list -> {
   List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
   try {
         res= callAPI2(list);
         return res;
      } catch(Exception e) {
      }
      return res; 
  });

  return new ArrayList<>(res.join());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  List<String> res1 = getList(id1);
  List<String> res2 = getList(id2);
}
```

Now the results are all empty.
I debugged and found that in the thenApply(), the list is empty, that's why the final result is empty. so thenApply() is still executed even the completablefuture is not completed.

How to correct the code?

Comment: Your list is empty because you swallow an error in the first future and return an empty list. Remove `try catch` (or re-throw as `RuntimeException`) in the first future to see what's going on with first call.

Comment: Your first code snippet starts with calling two different methods, `callAPI1` and `callFirstAPI2`. Your second snippet calls the same method, `callAPI1`, each time, but with different id arguments. Besides that, if “*looks like the … are not happening in the same thread*” is a problem, why are you using `supplyAsync` at all? Since your second approach is blocking the caller until completion anyway, you can use `List<String> res1 = callAPI2(callAPI1(id1)), res2 = callAPI2(callAPI1(id2));` to achieve the same.